# OCaml: polymorphic function on maps with generic keys

Tags: polymorphism, ocaml

In OCaml, are there polymorphic function on generic maps? I.e:

You can have: `f : 'a list -> bool` as the equivalent to `bool f<T> ([T] x)`

Can you also have something like: `f : ('k,'v) map -> bool` as the equivalent to `bool f<K,V> (Map<K,V> x)`?

If so, what is the correct syntax of the type signature, and how do you implement such a function (I ask since map is an abstract type and the only way to manipulate it is to use functions that you get by calling `Map.Make` on a concrete type)?

Thanks

Comment: which language is used for the equivalent definition?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on which type of generic map you use, and you have to make a distinction between the two parameters (the type of keys, and the type of values). If you use the [Map.Make](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Map.Make.html) functor of the default library, you can be generic on the type of values, but the type of keys will be fixed (by the functor instantiation): for a given key module `Key`, the maps generated by `module MyMap = Map.Make(Key)` have only one parameter, `'v MyMap.t`, so you can have `f : 'v MyMap.t -> bool`.

There are other libraries that provide so-called "polymorphic" maps with a type of the form `('k, 'v) pmap` that allow to be polymorphic over both the key and the value type. However, this generally comes at the cost of lesser static guarantees: if you were to change `'k` in a way that does not preserve the ordering on keys, you would get inconsistent results in a way that cannot be detected at compilation time.

Of course, you can implement additional function that work for any key type by enhancing the `Map.Make` functor itself (code untested):

```
module MyMake(K : Map.OrderedType) = struct
  include Map.Make(K)
  (* after the "include", all the functions provided by `Map.Make`
     are available in the module *)
  let is_not_empty m = not (is_empty m)
end

module MyMap = MyMake(String)
let foo = MyMap.is_not_empty (...)
```

(Remark: If you don't need a persistent collection (no copy/sharing/backtracking of values) and you don't care about the worst-case complexity (no use exposed to deny of service attacks by an user), you may also use hashtables, with the [Hashtbl](http://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/libref/Hashtbl.html) module that provides a `('k, 'v) Hashtbl.t` type. But the polymorphism on `'k` is not really present: you don't get any function that can make this parameter vary).